# IBM Watson Personality Insights token Authentication Python

Tags: python, ibm-watson, personality-insights

Can anyone please let me know the process to generate and use the token for IBM personality insights.

[Watson Personality Insights token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606896/watson-personality-insights-token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need to use HTTP GET request to the token with Python and get the token.

one.py:

```
def generateToken(username, password):

r = requests.get("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/personality-insights/api", auth=(username, password))
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            return r.text

def personalityRequest(text, token):
    base_url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/etc/etc....'
    headers = {'X-Watson-Authorization-Token': token, 'Content-Type': 'yourContextType'}
    r = requests.post(base_url, headers=headers, data={'body': text})
    return r.text
```

two.py:

```
token = one.generateToken()
ret = one.personalityRequest("your Text analyze...", token)
    print(ret)
```

Obs.: "Tokens have a time to live (TTL) of one hour, after which you can no longer use them to establish a connection with the service. Existing connections already established with the token are unaffected by the timeout. An attempt to pass an expired or invalid token elicits an HTTP 401 Unauthorized status code from DataPower. Your application code needs to be prepared to refresh the token in response to this return code."

See the official documentation about Tokens with IBM Watson [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/common/getting-started-tokens.html).

See the official [reference](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/authorization_v1.py) about using Authorization inside the SDK [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/watson_developer_cloud/authorization_v1.py#L29).

Comment: Hi - Thank you. this worked. But the thing is when this is in a loop for example I want to trigger Watson request in a for loop for 80 times with the same (username,password) or token. it gives me SSL error.

Comment: You need to open other question for this.

Comment: The question is already added. PFB                https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606896/watson-personality-insights-token?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45606896/watson-personality-insights-token?rq=1

Comment: The token is generated using the HTTP GET but still throws SSL error

Comment: Can you edit the question with your current code? I'll try to help you, and if I can't probably one IBM Professional will help you. I can help you to generate your token with this question, but, with the loop, another question is needs

Comment: New question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809208/ssl-error-ibm-watson-personality-insights-python